# Why Clang isn't generating any warnings for an incompatible casting?

Tags: c, clang, cc

I am trying to compile a simple [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17161099/7361690) with gcc and clang. the gcc generates a warning for an incomparable casting (great!). However, clang didn't generate any warnings! I have passed the same arguments for both:

```
cc -Wall -Wextra tmp3.c
gcc -Wall -Wextra tmp3.c
```

Am I passing all the necessary options to clang compiler or missing something? The clang [documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#id8) isn't a great help!

Code:

```
int main(void)
{
    void *b = (void *)0x12345678;
    int   a = (int)(unsigned long)b;
    int   c = (int)b;
    return a + c;
}
```

Clang version 3.8

Comment: Why do you _expect_ clang to emit a warning?

Comment: The best way to find warnings you may not know about is `-Weverything`. This option (only on Clang, sadly) turns on literally every warning. You're right, the documentation is not terribly helpful.

Comment: @Siguza: Why not? This is the most fundamental thing in any compiler for any programming language--a warning for an incompatible casting!

Comment: @KyleStrand: I didn't know about `-Weverything`, thanks for sharing. It didn't generate the necessary warning, instead it gave me:
`tmp3.c:7:2: warning: no newline at end of file [-Wnewline-eof]`
So impressed by clang so far!

Comment: @DavidJohn I would agree with both "incompatible assignments" as well as "anything that's obviously wrong", but casts are often neither, as the sole need for `(int)(unsigned long)` demonstrates. With explicit casts you basically tell the compiler that you know what you're doing.

Comment: @Siguza understood. If I add `(int)(unsigned long)` then I tell the compiler that I know what I am doing. However, if I cast a 64-bit value to a 32-bit value (without any hints to the compiler) then I expect the compiler to warn me. Anyway, my question was is there a way to make clang generate a warning for this situation or not?

Comment: Since you've tried `-Weverything`, you can now answer your own question (and mark it as accepted).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reached out to the clang developers (mailing list). I have got this response:

> In C++ mode, Clang errors on the line, same as everyone else.  In C
>   mode, however, conversions are typically more permissive.  In this
>   case, I suspect Clang should generate this warning as well.  It’ll
>   likely require a patch however.