# how this convertion done in c++ from unsigned char* to unsigned short? x= (unsigned char*)&x - (unsigned char*) 0x8888;

Tags: c++

how this convertion done from unsigned char* to unsigned short?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    unsigned short x;
    x= (unsigned char*)&x - (unsigned char*) 0x8888;
    cout<<us<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

when I am trying to add like this

```
x= (unsigned char*)&x + (unsigned char*) 0x8888;
```

Then error comes up. it says "invalid operands of types 'unsigned char*' and 'unsigned char*' to binary 'operator+' " please help me to understand this syntax.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: There is no conversion from `unsigned char *` to `unsigned short` in your code. The subtraction has higher precedence than the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Subtraction operation can be performed on two address data type but not addition.
For addition, either both operand of `+` shall be of arithmetic type or one operand shall be a pointer and other shall be an integer type.

#### C++11-§ 5.7/1:

> For addition, either both operands shall have arithmetic or unscoped enumeration type, or one operand shall be a pointer to a completely-defined object type and the other shall have integral or unscoped enumeration type.

Comment: Brother this not working   x= (unsigned char*)&x + 88    i have changed second operand to int.

Comment: I am trying this code "x= (unsigned char*)&x + 88". Then "error: invalid conversion from 'short unsigned int*' to 'short unsigned int' [-fpermissive]|"

Comment: `(unsigned char*)&x + 88` will give an `unsigned char*` value. `x` is `unsigned short` type. Error/warning is legit.

Comment: x= (unsigned short*)&x + 88; i changed (unsigned char*) to (unsigned short*)      Then "error: invalid conversion from 'short unsigned int*' to 'short unsigned int' [-fpermissive]|"

Comment: Do you know the difference between pointer and `int` data types?

Answer (score 0):

You could convert pointer to `int/short/long` using `cstdint C++11` as below, But I'm not certain whether it is advisable to add pointers as mentioned by `@haccks`

```
#include<iostream>
#include <cstdint>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    unsigned short x;
    //x= (unsigned char*)&x + (unsigned char*) 0x8888;
    x = static_cast<unsigned short>(reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(&x)) + static_cast<unsigned short>(0x8888);
    cout<<x<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21574449/why-is-cast-from-x-to-y-loses-precision-a-hard-error-and-what-is-suitable) for more information.